# Little annoying white bar at bottom of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am goofing around trying to learn Java Swing and whether I create a window and try to set it's background color to completely black I get this annoying white bar at the bottom.
[Just like this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhyfD.png)

Here is  my code:

```
      package com.company;

      import java.awt.*;
      import javax.swing.*;

      public class Main {

         public static void main(String[] args) {
         JFrame window = new JFrame("Pong!");

         Container backG = window.getContentPane();
         backG.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
         window.setSize(800, 600);
         window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         window.setVisible(true);
        }
      }
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdsXe.png) here. Note that the size of that image is 600 x 120 to make it smaller, but the same effect happened at 600 x 60. Having said that, a GUI should be packed, and it should be created and shown on the EDT. BTW - what OS & settings are you using to see a purple frame?

Comment: Windows 10 and I am not sure about settings. I noticed the bar disappears when I resize the window though.

Comment: 1) *try to set it's background color to completely black* - then use `Color.BLACK` which is more easily understood than "new Color(0, 0, 0)". 2) I also don't have a problem on Wiondows 10.

Comment: Me: *"same effect happened at 600 x 60"* My bad. It was the same size as set in the original source code. 800 x 600. *"I noticed the bar disappears when I resize the window though."* `pack()` the frame. I'd predict 90%+ chance that will solve the problem.

Comment: I set it to Color.BLACK and packed the frame, but still nothing.